# Is it possible to wake-on-lan an Hyper-V host with an external virtual switch configured

Tags: networking, hyper-v, wake-on-lan

Pretty much the title. I am trying to enable wake-on-lan on my Hyper-V host machine, I tried multiple mac addresses after enabling Wake on magic packet on my host machine (the one from the Virtual Switch, from my physical Ethernet card) but none seem to work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It is possible.  Have you googled it by chance?  [Hyper-V Wake-On-Lan](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hyper-v+wake-on-lan&atb=v117-1&ia=web)

Comment: @JW0914 I only find ways to enable WOL on the guest machines and not the host one, it also seems that it is not trivial because the hypervisor takes the ownership of the physical NIC and therefore the host system can't respond to WOL packets :/

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to get wake-on-LAN working on a Hyper-V host is to install on the host a network adapter that supports WoL and do not assign it to a virtual switch.

For many scenarios, this means you'll need two network adapters. Set up one adapter that can handle WoL and will never be used by Hyper-V. You can then assign the other adapter to a virtual switch and let the guest VMs use it.

Also, be sure that your host machine is in a sleep or suspend mode in which Microsoft supports WoL. Microsoft has documentation ([here for workstation editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2776718/wake-on-lan-wol-behavior-in-windows-8-windows-8-1-and-windows-10) as of this writing) on supported sleep states for WoL. You can run `powercfg /a` as an administrator to see what sleep states the machine you're on supports. I've heard of someone who had a problem with this and it turned out that what he needed to do was update a drivers for a device that was showing in `powercfg` as preventing all the supported low-power states.

Answer (score 1):

(Hyper-V 2019 command line)

```
POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_programmable

...   (Find your LAN adapter)

POWERCFG /deviceenablewake "<your LAN adapter>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\admin>POWERCFG /DEVICEQUERY wake_programmable
Remote Desktop Keyboard Device
Remote Desktop Mouse Device
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
Microsoft PS/2 Mouse
Standard PS/2 Keyboard
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller


C:\Users\admin>POWERCFG /deviceenablewake "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2"

C:\Users\admin>POWERCFG /deviceenablewake "Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller"

C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.